# Running Parallel ForEach with timeouts

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a set of trade objects and each of them have 2 properties - spot price and forward price.I need to set the spot price property and forward price in the background as they are getting those prices from third party services which are slow. I need to only compute the forward price if the spot price is fetched successfully OR the spot price is fetched in a certain duration of time.

Here is the code:

```
public class Trade
{
    public double SpotPrice { get; set; }
    public double ForwardPrice { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var trades = new List<Trade> 
    {
        new Trade(), new Trade(), new Trade(), new Trade()
    };

    Parallel.ForEach(trades, (trade) =>
    {
        var pipeline = Task.Factory.StartNew<Trade>(() =>
        {
            trade.SpotPrice = WaitAndReturnPrice(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Console.WriteLine("Spot Price:" + trade.SpotPrice);
            return trade;

        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var tradeObject = t.Result;

            tradeObject.ForwardPrice = WaitAndReturnPrice(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            Console.WriteLine("Forward Price:" + trade.ForwardPrice);
        });
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static Random random = new Random();

private static double WaitAndReturnPrice(TimeSpan fromSeconds)
{
    Thread.Sleep(fromSeconds);
    return random.NextDouble();
}
```

I have added a method `WaitAndReturnPrice` to simulate that the prices are getting fetched followed by a delay.

I'm facing multiple issues with this approach, mainly due to lack of my understanding of TPL. The issues are:

1. How do I introduce a timeout while calculating the spot price? i.e I have to say that the fetching of Spot price should be completed in 2 seconds or else dont bother continuing with computing the Forward Price.
2. How can I handle any exception happening while fetching the spot price, and if it happens, how can I abort computing the forward price as well?
3. If the above 1 or 2 or both happens with 1 of the trade objects, how can I continue with the rest of them and still try to fetch the spot price and forward price for them?

Can you please help me with this?

Please note that I'm using **.NET4.0** and not above that (so no async and await).

Comment: You can use `async`-`await` on .Net 4.0 through [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), though it requires VS 2012.

Comment: I recommend you either use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) or `async` for this, both of which support .NET 4.0. You can force parallel code (TPL) to work, but it's not an ideal fit for your problem, so your solution will be awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a parallel loop, I'll fetch the prices in the background using the thread pool:

```
foreach (var trade in trades) {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FetchPrice), trade);
} 

. . . .

void FetchPrice(object tradeObj)
{
  var trade = (Trade)tradeObj;
  try {
    trade.SpotPrice = WaitAndReturnPrice(TimeSpan.FromSecond(2));
    // . . . compute forward price ...   
  } catch (TimeOutException) {
    // . . . compute forward price in case of time-out fetching the spot price...   
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    // ...handle other errors
  }
}
```

The handling of the time-out (throwing a 'TimeOutException`) must be done inside the function that fetches the price, because it depends on the exact mechanism that is used there.